# how to download exe file into memory and execution from memory?

Tags: c#, memory

i want download a.exe file to memory and execut directly from memory without saving a.exe in disk

and
No matter how hard I tried, I did not succeed
I can not read and execute binaries inside the stream

my code :

```
private void DownloadStream()
{
    string uri = "http://site/a.exe";
    string results = "N/A";

    try
    {
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
        HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());

        results = sr.ReadToEnd();
        sr.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

please help me

Comment: Executing a file directly in memory means you have to take on all the tasks the operating system does in order to do so. This means you need to allocate a new process for it, map the executable memory into that process, do memory fixups, initialize the execution context properly for security and whatnot, and then finally start the process correctly. None of these steps are trivial. You're much better off writing the file to disk and trying to execute it that way.

Comment: Can you explain WHY you want to do this?   There may be a better way to do what you are trying to do.  Also, what have you tried?  Your code will download a stream into memory.  What you have done to execute it, that doesn't work?

Comment: Please talk us through which options from https://www.google.com/search?q=executable+file+from+memory+c%23 you have already tried.

Comment: You need a loader.  An exe file cannot be directly executed.  The memory segments must be assigned by a loader to physical memory (requires system credentials).  When you run from a file windows has a loader that automatically runs.  So you would need to run a loader before executing.

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion its only possible to save the `.exe` file in the `temp-directory` and execute it there.